# Trying to have large canvas overflow with scrollbars using CSS flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am trying to essentially have a very large canvas (10000x10000 +) with scrollbars as overflow. As I understand it, the canvas itself cannot overflow, and so I want it's parent (a div) to handle the overflow.

I've managed to do this when I was not using CSS Flex/FlexBox but now that I am trying to use it, I cannot get it to work.

I've looked all around to try and understand how CSS Flex works but this is my first time using it so I do not have any real understanding of what I should try doing to get it to work.

Here is at a basic level what I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/vbqpmy5r/10/

Here is my css file:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
}

#container > #canvasContainer {
  flex: 1;
}

#container > #inspectorContainer {
  flex: 0 0 20vw;
}

#buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#buttonContainer > button {
  height: 3em;
}

#canvasContainer {
  display: flex;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#previewContainer {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 10em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#canvas {
  flex: 1 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button>
  Button 1
  </button>
  <button>
  Button 2
  </button>
  <button>
  Button 3
  </button>
  <button>
  Button 4
  </button>

</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="previewContainer">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

As for the Javascript, all I do is set the canvas' width and height to 10000.

I want the canvas container to have scrollbars so that I can go through and scroll all 10000 x 10000 pixels of the canvas; as it is, setting the size appears to have done nothing.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `align-items:flex-start` to `#canvasContainer` and set

```
#canvas {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

See the snipet below:

```js
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.width = 10000;
  canvas.height = 10000;
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
}

#container > #canvasContainer {
  flex: 1;
}

#container > #inspectorContainer {
  flex: 0 0 20vw;
}

#buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#buttonContainer > button {
  height: 3em;
}

#canvasContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#previewContainer {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 10em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#canvas {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button>
  Button 1
  </button>
  <button>
  Button 2
  </button>
  <button>
  Button 3
  </button>
  <button>
  Button 4
  </button>

</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="previewContainer">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't have set the #canvasContainer display property to "flex". It must be "block". So you don't need to set flex property for the #canvas because it's parent is not a flex container anymore. Also you should remove the "overflow" property from the #canvas and move it to its parent which is #canvasContainer.

Also you have set width and height of the #canvas to 100%. Why did you do that? If you want to set width and height of the canvas in the CSS, set it to 10000px or just leave it and set it with JavaScript.

So something like this should solve the problem:

```
#canvasContainer {
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#canvas {
  width: 10000px;
  height: 10000px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Setting the canvas width like `canvas.width = 10000` is setting the scene ( inside of canvas ) size.

Think about that like a `<div>` which has `background-image` and that background has a size of 10000x10000. You need to set that `<div>`'s width equal to 10000 to affect regardless of actual background's size.

to reach the desired effect, you should set its `canvas.style.width` equal to **10000**. [take a look at this live version](https://jsfiddle.net/tp6r5g03/) to see if it's what you want or not.